# Receive message directly to my app ,without going to KIK API

Tags: android, api, messaging, android-notifications, kik

I am using KIK API to sent and receive message.

I can able to receive message to my app, But it is received through KIK messagener APP only.

 [image: KIK API]

 I want to receive message directly to my app.
On click of notification alert of the message. I want to show the message directly in my app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Receiving messages directly in your app is not a part of the API and is not possible at all.

Also, the Kik native API was deprecated roughly 2 years ago and shouldn't be considered for building new apps. The web-based APIs should be used instead (dev.kik.com)

Comment: Is the native API mapped out anywhere?  Just because it is deprecated doesn't mean it isn't useful - the web-based APIs are very limited, in the sense that you are confined to only develop apps that work within the kik app itself.

Comment: The native API has been deprecated for more than two years and is entirely non-functional on iOS. We do not support this anymore